# Can't see deployed Biztalk Project Assemblies in GAC?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, gac, windows-server-2012, biztalk-2013r2

I have a Biztalk project that has the following settings:

```
General > Redeploy > True
Local Machine > Install to Global Assembly Cache > True
```

All projects involved have an SNK file generated.  However, I removed a reference and it hasn't been cleaned out of the GAC [according to biztalk documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547052.aspx).  When I attempt to locate my installed assembly in c:\windows\assembly, I cannot find my BiztalkProject.DLL or the BiztalkLibraries.DLL project there.  Is it possible this is a permissions issue, or am I dealing with a different issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C:\Windows\Assembly is the CLR 2.0 GAC (.Net 2.0 through 3.5).

If you are using BizTalk Server 2010 or later, you will find the GAC'd Assemblies in the CLR 4.0 GAC at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Answer (score 4):

You can also use gacutil.exe.  Open the Developer Command Prompt, and type

```
gacutil /l | find "AssemblyName"
```

to check if it's in the GAC and

```
gacutil /u AssemblyName
```

to remove it.  Note that AssemblyName can just be the first part of the Fully Qualified Name.